# Cleaning Ubuntu temporary files if they exist

Tags: cleanup

I need to do a lot of cleaning in my Virtual Machine whose Operating System is Ubuntu.

Normally in Windows, there is this kind of directory that contain temporary files and that should be cleaned :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp
```

Does it exist such a directory in Ubuntu? If yes, what is it?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Linux distributions usually store their temporary files in `/tmp`. Ubuntu does so too, so the temporary files are in `/tmp`, but there is no need to empty them manually, because it is emptied on every reboot by default.

Also applications may store their cache in your home directory, these locations vary by application, but well behaving apps store their cache in `~/.cache`.