# Where are incomplete downloads stored in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: downloads

I started downloading a video from savefrom.net. Due to some error the video did not download completely. I came to know that you can't watch the incomplete video that's ok but i have very less space in my hard disk. Where is incomplete downloaded video stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which application you were using. For Firefox, it's where you downloaded it to, probably the Downloads folder in your home directory. For Chrome, I think the temporary file gets deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Incomplete downloads are stored in /tmp directory in Ubuntu. Unfinished or corrupt files are automatically deleted after each reboot.

reference:
[Cleaning Ubuntu temporary files if they exist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395607/cleaning-ubuntu-temporary-files-if-they-exist)